# How to padleft with a variable number of digits?

Tags: matlab

I kknow I can pad a number up to 3 digits this way:

```
prematrix = sprintf('%03d', prematrix);
```

but what if I want a number of digits stored in `a` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Matlab, but just googled [strcat](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) and this should work (untested) for 12 zeros:

```
a='%0';
b='12';
c='d';
d=strcat(a,b,c);
prematrix = sprintf(d, prematrix);
```